# How to combine additional features with tfidf vector

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the following method to train a linear regressor to predict retweets of tweets. I am using 'text' as the feature and 'retweet_count' as the target to be predicted. However, I have several additional features in my data such as **hasMedia,   hasHashtag, followers_count, sentiment** (which are numerical features). How can I combine these features with '**text**' that was converted to tfidf vector?

I already tried concatenating pandas dataframes. And then When I give a new test data the features mismatch. Please check my question in [Attributes mismatch between training and testing data in sklearn - linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747463/attributes-mismatch-between-training-and-testing-data-in-sklearn-linear-regres)

```
def predict_retweets(dataset):
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, stop_words='english', lowercase=False)

    keyword_response = tfidf.fit_transform(dataset['text']).toarray()

    X = keyword_response
    y = dataset['retweet_count']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    regressor = LinearRegression()

    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})

    print(df)

    return None
```

> Sample of data

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append tfidf to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961747/append-tfidf-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I already tried that. Please check my issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747463/attributes-mismatch-between-training-and-testing-data-in-sklearn-linear-regres

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to help with some samples of the data

Comment: nixon I have added a sample of data

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is no longer relevant but maybe this can help others.

The solution is to use **numpy's hstack**.

Here is the code:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Sample data
dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    "text": [
        "are red violets are blue iF you want to buy us here is a clue our eye amp cheek palettc",
        "is it too late now to say sorry",
        "oh no please email your order to social amp we can help this is a newest offer",
        "its best applied with our buffer brush",
        "dead",
        "our amazonian clay Full coverage Foundation comes in 40 shades of creamy goodn",
        "which one are you",
        "it got winter wanderlust swap the For with holiday in paradise collection packed with",
        "tartelettes peep our ig story For",
        "it nothing quite as pretty as a clutter",
        "hot deal alert pick up our shape tape matte or hydrating foundation for only 23 usd",
        "want to learn 2 ways to get with our busy gal brows tinted brow gel then head on ove",
        "please dm us your email address amp we can help",
        "the flamingo and Dineapplethemed palettes products and tools are bright fun and e9"
    ],
    "hasMedia" : [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    "hasHashtag": [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
    "followers_count": [801745] * 14,
    "sentiment": [0.0772, 0, 0.5684, 0.6696, -0.7213, 0.5093, 0, 0.7845, 0, -0.428, 0, 0.3058, 0.6124, 0.7351],
    "retweet_count": [17,94, 0,0,0,13,88,37,3,10,11,1,0,28]
})

# Create a TfidfVectorizer for text feature extraction
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', lowercase=False)

# Calculate the TF-IDF features from the 'text' column of the dataset
keyword_response = tfidf.fit_transform(dataset['text']).toarray()

# Combine TF-IDF features with the numerical features
X = np.hstack((keyword_response, dataset[["hasMedia", "hasHashtag", "followers_count", "sentiment"]]))

# Set the target variable y as 'retweet_count'
y = dataset['retweet_count']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a Linear Regression model
regressor = LinearRegression()

# Train the model on the training data
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

# Create a DataFrame to display actual and predicted values
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})

# Print the DataFrame with actual and predicted values
print(df)
```